# Behavior Subject - Value is not updated - Angular 4

Tags: angular, rxjs, observable

I am trying to workout on the Behavior subject. Please find the following snippets.

dashboard.component.js

```
export class DashboardComponent implements OnInit {
inputObjResponse = [];
constructor(private http: Http, private GetjsondataService: GetjsondataService) { }
ngOnInit() {
    var that = this;
    this.GetjsondataService.getValuesFromJson()
    this.GetjsondataService.data.subscribe(
        data => {console.log("new data1",data);this.inputObjResponse = data},
        error => console.log(error),
        () => console.log("completed")
    )                              
}}
```

header.component.js

```
export class HeaderComponent implements OnInit {
constructor(private GetjsondataService: GetjsondataService) { }
ngOnInit() {
    this.GetjsondataService.data.subscribe(
        data => {console.log("new data1",data)},
        error => console.log(error),
        () => {
            console.log("completed in header");
            this.GetjsondataService.setJsonvaluesToShare("")
                }
        )
}}
```

getjsondata.service.ts

```
export class GetjsondataService {
inputObjResponse:any;
public source = new BehaviorSubject<any>('');
data = this.source.asObservable();
constructor(private http:Http) { }
getValuesFromJson() {
    this.http.get('./json/inputjson.json')
    .map((response:Response) => response.json())
    .subscribe(
        data => this.inputObjResponse =  data,
        error => console.log('#1 Error:', error),
        () =>   { 
            console.log(this.inputObjResponse);
            this.source.next(this.inputObjResponse)
            this.source.complete();                
        }
    );             
}
setJsonvaluesToShare(inputjsonrespose) {
    this.source.next(inputjsonrespose)
    this.source.complete();
    console.log(inputjsonrespose)
}}
```

I am getting the following results for now.

- getting null value initially in the dashboard component and header component in the subscribe log
- following that, the null value is being updated to an object with the use of http service in the getjsondata service.

So far everything is working exactly as I understand the Behavior Subject. But when I try to update the values again using the

```
this.GetjsondataService.setJsonvaluesToShare("")
```

in complete function of header component, the value is not updated in dashboard and header component.

I am not sure why the value is not updated, Please guide me where I am wrong in understanding the logic.

I have explained it clearly as much as i could, I can explain further if anything is not clear.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From docs

> onCompleted() Notifies the Observer that the Observable has finished
>   sending push-based notifications.

So it will effectively "close" the subject as you signalled that no other emmisions will be made. Remove

```
this.source.complete();
```

Comment: Ok Got it now. Thanks. So now my question is, How can i update the value again when subscription is complete. Any idea?

Comment: Your subscription wont be completed if you wont close the stream. Maybe your will have to resubscribe afterward - I don't exactly gets your point here. Your callback will get emited values as  long as yu either close the stream (with complete()) or you explicitly unsubscribe the subscription. Threat it as "listeners" to some async data, and react properly (eg update UI) when such data comes.

Answer (score 0):

As @Antoniossss already pointed out, *complete()* closes the stream and you will not get the latest value of the Behavior Subject.

You'll need to keep that Subject open if you want to get the latest value from your Observable. Also, make sure to unsubscribe the subscriptions in your components (in most cases you'll want to do that in OnDestroy Angular hook - either by unsubscribing the subscription object or using the RxJS operators like *takeUntil* or *takeWhile*).